# How to set different color of every box of Staggered GridView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to set the different color of every box of Staggered GridView in Flutter?

[image]

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                    new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2.5 : 1.7),
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want random colors try [random_color package](https://pub.dev/packages/random_color)

```
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart'; //You can use this package    

itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
     color: setColor(index),
     child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
        ],
     ),
   ),
   staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
     StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2.5 : 1.7),
       mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
       crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
),

Color setColor(int index){
  return index.isEven ? Colors.white : Colors.lime[300]; //if you want to change between 2 colors

  //You can use random_color package
  return randomColor.randomColor(
    colorHue: ColorHue.multiple([ColorHue.white, ColorHue.blue] //Define all the hues you want in your range
  )
}
```

You can define your own list of colors and choose it based on the index, or just use the random color package and let it choose it for you